# Copy Sublime Syntax from one theme to another

Tags: sublime-text-2, syntax-highlighting

I like to use Sublime Text 2, but the theme I use (Pastels on Dark) doesn't have the syntax for certain key words in C#. As I understand it the theme is linked to the syntax (or visa versa)

Below are two screenshots of the same script, one in Monokai, the other in Pastels on Dark (my preferred choice). You'll notice that lots of keywords don't show up on the Pastels on dark theme (Only using, for & if in this instance).

Without being a Rex Ex wizard, is there an easy way to find all the keywords that are being used in Monokai and copy them to the Pastels on Dark theme?

[image: Sublime Text Monokai c#]
[image: Sublime Text Pastels on Dark]

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly you're trying to do? As it stands now, your question is very unclear.

Comment: It's okay Matt I managed to figure it out - with your help! This is exactly what I neeed! [Sublime Colour Scheme Editor](http://mattdmo.com/guide-to-installing-colorschemeeditor-for-sublime-text-3/)

Comment: Glad I could help! Just for my knowledge, how did you find my blog post?

Comment: I can see you typing through the window! No, actually it was a freak accident, if you must know. Most people use notepad ++ here in the studio & I couldn't find any help on SO or SU, despite lots of searches and research. Then oddly, I got distracted & started looking at the profiles of all the Maxscript users on SO, and found your blog and couldn't miss the link to Do you love Sublime Text?